# Need help setting up json array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, jsonp

A database query returns several rows which I loop through as follows:

```
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

        $data[$row->post_id]['post_id']         = $row->post_id;
        $data[$row->post_id]['post_type']       = $row->post_type;
        $data[$row->post_id]['post_text']       = $row->post_text;
    }
```

If I `json_encode` the resulting array (`$a['stream']`) I get

```
{
    "stream": {
        "1029": {
            "post_id": "1029",
            "post_type": "1",
            "post_text": "bla1",
        },
        "1029": {
            "post_id": "1030",
            "post_type": "3",
            "post_text": "bla2",
        },
        "1029": {
            "post_id": "1031",
            "post_type": "2",
            "post_text": "bla3",            
        }
    }
}
```

But the `json` should actually look like this:

```
{
    "stream": {
        "posts": [{
            "post_id": "1029",
            "post_type": "1",
            "post_text": "bla1",
        },
        {
            "post_id": "1030",
            "post_type": "3",
            "post_text": "bla2",
        },
        {
            "post_id": "1031",
            "post_type": "2",
            "post_text": "bla3",            
        }]
    }
}
```

How should I build my array to get this `json` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways, this is what you should do:

```
...
$posts = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $post = array();
    $post['post_id']         = $row->post_id;
    $post['post_type']       = $row->post_type;
    $post['post_text']       = $row->post_text;
    $posts[] = $post;
}
$data['posts'] = $posts;
...
```

A bit of explanation: you have to build up an object from the information you are getting from the database, that's `$post`. Each one of these objects need to be added together to an array, that's `$posts`. This array of posts coming from the database are set to the key `posts` of `$data`, that's `$data['posts']`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

http://codepad.viper-7.com/zPHCm0

```
<?php
$myData = array();
$myData['posts'][] = array('post_id' => 3, 'post_type' => 343, 'post_text' => 'sky muffin pie');
$myData['posts'][] = array('post_id' => 4, 'post_type' => 111, 'post_text' => 'Mushroom chocolate banana');
$myData['posts'][] = array('post_id' => 231, 'post_type' => 888, 'post_text' => 'Cucumber strawberry in the sky');

$theStream['stream'] = $myData;

$json = json_encode($theStream);

echo 'JSON:<Br/>';
echo $json;
```

The above gives me:

```
{
    "stream":
    {   "posts":[
            {"post_id":3,"post_type":343,"post_text":"sky muffin pie"},
            {"post_id":4,"post_type":111,"post_text":"Mushroom chocolate banana"},
            {"post_id":231,"post_type":888,"post_text":"Cucumber strawberry in the sky"}]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $data['posts']['post_id']         = $row->post_id;
    $data['posts']['post_type']       = $row->post_type;
    $data['posts']['post_text']       = $row->post_text;
}
```